# bootstrap understanding source code directories

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched for a day to better understand the directory structure of the Bootstrap 3 source code.  I would greatly appreciate some perspective on this.

I get the use of Grunt to compile the contents of the **dist** directory, but why, in the examples, are there links to an **assets** directory outside of **dist**?  How should this be addressed while customizing a site built on Bootstrap?

For example if my \home\mysite.com directory looked like the one below, would I not add my customization to the less/js/fonts directories within the **bootstrap** directory, update **Gruntfile.js** accordingly, and compile everything into my **public_html** directory?  Or, should the public directory always be the **dist** folder?  If I'm building a wordPress theme or drupal theme would i then copy and paste those Grunt-compiled bootstrap js/css/fonts resources into the theme folder?

I realize anything could be customized, but I would prefer to tackle it as intended.  I'm just trying to wrap my head around something unfamiliar.

Thank you in advance!

```
mysite.com
├── bower_components
│   ├── bootstrap
│   │   ├── CNAME
│   │   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│   │   ├── Gruntfile.js
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── _config.yml
│   │   ├── bower.json
│   │   ├── composer.json
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   ├── docs
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── grunt
│   │   ├── js
│   │   ├── less
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── test-infra
│   └── jquery
│       ├── MIT-LICENSE.txt
│       ├── bower.json
│       ├── dist
│       └── src
└── public_html
    ├── css
    ├── js
    ├── fonts
    └── index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've searched for a day to better understand the directory structure of the Bootstrap 3 source code.

Was the official documentation on the topic somehow lacking?: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included

> why, in the examples, are there links to an assets directory outside of dist? How should this be addressed while customizing a site built on Bootstrap?

Those links are to docs-specific JS files. You should simply not link to them in your production site in the first place. However, some files in `/docs/dist` are just convenience copies of files from `/dist`; for those, you just need to change the paths (like you'd normally do anyway when copying from an example template).

As to whether/how to tweak the Gruntfile, FWICT it's basically a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: Thx for the feedback.  

I do feel the jump from "Compiling CSS and JavaScript" to "Basic template" is lacking.

So if you wanted to start a build with one of the examples you would copy it into the dist folder, right?  Wouldn't you then need those js resources from the assets directory as well.

It's not a problem getting it all to work within the dist directory....or outside the bootstrap folder all together...I'm just posing the ? to better understand if this is their intention.

Thx again!

Comment: There is no applicable intention. For end-users, Bootstrap's Gruntfile was written to merely build the static JS & CSS assets that are output to the `/dist/` folder. Period. Full stop. You can of course adapt it to do more or use a different directory structure, but Bootstrap doesn't impose or recommend any particular directory structure for a whole-site build/deployment.

Comment: "Wouldn't you then need those js resources from the assets directory as well" I've edited the answer to add some additional clarification.

Comment: "if you wanted to start a build with one of the examples you would copy it into the dist folder, right? " Personally, no; I'd copy the HTML file into my web framework's templates directory.

Comment: What if I want to customize my BS-based theme, without reverting to writing CSS? Should I include my own .less files into the Grunt compilation process, or would it be better to do this outside the BS directory...setting up my own Grunt file in another directory?  In either scenario, would you add an automated process or a maybe a symlink (for local dev) from your public_html directory (for instance a WP theme directory) back to the BS dist directory to avoid having to copy and paste each time .less files are updated causing the css to change?  Thank you again for your time and consideration!